# How to match and extract a regular expression pattern?

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string like so - SampleReleaseFY20Q3.STRY0122544.Developer.SDLCRework.6

Now, I would like to extract the pattern STRY******* and store it in a variable. So in this case, I would like to extract STRY0122544 and store it in a variable.

Any help with this is appreciated!

Thanks,
Raskill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use string `match` here:

```js
var input = "SampleReleaseFY20Q3.STRY0122544.Developer.SDLCRework.6";
var output = input.match(/STRY\d+/)[0];
console.log(output);
```